# Screen recording stop recording after a few minutes with Quicktime

Tags: video, screen-capture, quicktime, ventura, screen-recording

When recording the screen with Quicktime or other software like Camtasia, the screen gets frozen after a few minutes.

I'm recording the second monitor (4k), and after a few minutes of recording, I can see the video doesn't continue to be recorded.

The audio (from mic) continues normally, but the video stays stuck for the rest of the video.

In other scenarios, the video continued, but the mic get noisy.

I noticed it may be related to high cpu usage, considering I'm recording computer programming, and some softwares use more cpu. However, it was not a problem in the past.

It's a macbook pro i9, 6-core, 32gb ram. Shouldn't be a problem I think.

Perhaps it's related to the last update (Ventura).

Any insight/idea would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem stopped after upgrading to a new MBP. :(